# variance of multiple variables

Tags: probability, self-study, variance

Mean or $E(X)$ is linear, so it's valid to write $$E(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) = E(x_1) + E(x_2) + E(x_3)$$ But $Var(x)$ is not linear, so we write $$Var(ax_1 + bx_2 ) = a^2Var(x_1) + b^2Var(x_2) + 2ab\;Cov(x_1,x_2)$$ In the following question finding mean is easy and I'm getting it $40$mm. But I'm finding it difficult to get the variance. If I use independency I could simply add the variances but that is giving me wrong answer. Since no  unit is specified in the question I'm assuming that they are asking variance of sample mean. So, I'm thinking some thing like this
$$0.02 = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{100} \Rightarrow \sigma_1^2 = 2$$
$\sigma_1^2$ is the variance for 100 lamination.
$$0.01 = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{200} \Rightarrow \sigma_2^2 = 2$$ 
$\sigma_2^2$ is the variance for $2*100$ coatings.

$$var(core) = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{100} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{200} = 0.03$$
This is not the answer. Any suggestions?

> Q. The mean thickness and variance of silicon steel laminations are $0.2$ mm and $0.02$ respectively. The varnish insulation is applied on both the sides of the laminations. The mean thickness of one side
>   insulation and its variance are $0.1$ mm and $0.01$ respectively. If the transformer core is made using
>   $100$ such varnish coated laminations, the mean thickness and variance of the core respectively are ?

Answer is $40$ mm and $0.24$.

Comment: Please consider adding `self-study` tag.